# Require radio button html and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following html code

```
<input type="radio" name="months" value="TBI-6">
<input type="radio" name="months" value="UNI-6">
```

And i have this submitt button

```
    $('#button-confirm').on('click', function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'index.php?route=payment/zero_rate/confirm',
    cache: false,
      data:{
        egn: $('#input-payment-egn').val(), 
        months: $('input[name=months]:checked').parent().text() + $('input[name=months]:checked').val()
      },
    beforeSend: function() {
      $('#button-confirm').button('loading');
    },
    complete: function() {
      $('#button-confirm').button('reset');
    },
    success: function() {
      location = '<?php echo $continue; ?>';
    }
  });
});
```

How can i validate this two radio buttons? I dont want to let the user to submitt the form and leave the page without choosing one of the radio buttons?

Comment: learn about `preventDefault()` function https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[name=months]:checked').length
```

should tell you ***how many*** radio buttons in the group **are checked**.
So verify that is above `0` before you continue with the form submission.

Answer (score 0):

Check the radio button if checked

```
<input type="radio" name="months" value="TBI-6" class="radiobtn">
<button id="button-confirm">
 Submit
</button>
```

```js
$('#button-confirm').on('click', function() {

if($('.radiobtn').is(':checked')) { alert("it's checked");


  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'index.php?route=payment/zero_rate/confirm',
    cache: false,
      data:{
        egn: $('#input-payment-egn').val(), 
        months: $('input[name=months]:checked').parent().text() + $('input[name=months]:checked').val()
      },
    beforeSend: function() {
      $('#button-confirm').button('loading');
    },
    complete: function() {
      $('#button-confirm').button('reset');
    },
    success: function() {
      location = '<?php echo $continue; ?>';
    }
  });
 } else {
      alert("it's not checked");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="months" value="TBI-6" class="radiobtn">
<button id="button-confirm">
 Submit
</button>
```

Comment: Yes but after i see the alert, and click okay, the page is continue to `location = '<?php echo $continue; ?>';`

Comment: @ДобромирМилчев, move ajax within the if statement. I updated the code

Comment: Now its freezing on this function`beforeSend: function() {
      $('#button-confirm').button('loading');`

Comment: Do you have any idea how can i fix it?